# Pass ng-model as argument in directive angualjrs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am writing a directive in `AngularJs` and I want to pass `ng-model` as an argument.

```
<div class="col-md-7"><time-picker></time-picker></div>
```

The directive is:

```
    app.directive('timePicker', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: '<input type="text" class="form-control time-picker" ng-model="emp.signin">',
        link: function ($scope, element, form) {
            $(element).timepicker({'timeFormat': 'H:i:s'});
        }
    }
})
```

It is working fine, and here the `ng-model` is `emp.signin`. I want to be able to pass this `ng-model` dynamically as argument

How is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
<div class="col-md-7"><time-picker model-value="emp.signin"></time-picker></div>
```

Angular

```
app.directive('timePicker', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: '<input type="text" class="form-control time-picker"ng-model="modelValue ">',
        scope: {
            modelValue : '=',
        }
        link: function ($scope, element, form) {
            $(element).timepicker({'timeFormat': 'H:i:s'});
        }
    }
})
```

**Explaination**

> The `“=”` prefix will create a two-way binding between the parent and
>   directive scope and it’ll always expect the attribute value to be the
>   model name which means you cannot provide an expression as the value
>   of attribute mapped to “=” prefix.

For reference: "http://www.undefinednull.com/2014/02/11/mastering-the-scope-of-a-directive-in-angularjs/"

Comment: change the name of the attribute you are passing to anything else. As this is the error for multiple directives are applied on same dom element.

Comment: yea.. I am using multiple directive